Tikz picture messes up the layout of my beamer frame
I am writing a beamer presentation, and in one frame, I want to do a layout with four sections. I managed (with the help of ChatGPT) to do it with minipage in the following way:
However, I found one problem: when adding a Tikz picture to the 4th section, the 3rd section moves down instead of being vertically aligned (as I want).
While I am able to fix it by adding a vspace{0pt} at the beginning of the 4th section, this screams that there is probably something wrong with this approach.
Is there a better way to fix this problem?
(Note that by "fixing" the problem, I mean the problem of having the correct layout, so if my approach is fundamentally wrong, I would also appreciate indications on the better way to do it.)
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
    % Top-left minipage
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.4\textheight][t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \vspace{1pt}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    % Top-right minipage
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.4\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor.
            \item Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \vfill
    
    % Bottom-left minipage
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.6\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat.
            \item Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    % Bottom-right minipage
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.6\textheight][t]{0.35\textwidth}
%        \vspace{0pt}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick, red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


t will align the baseline of the first line. Use T instead:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
    % Top-left minipage
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.4\textheight][t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \vspace{1pt}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    % Top-right minipage
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.4\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor.
            \item Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \vfill
    
    % Bottom-left minipage
    \begin{minipage}[T][0.6\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat.
            \item Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    % Bottom-right minipage
    \begin{minipage}[T][0.6\textheight][t]{0.35\textwidth}
%        \vspace{0pt}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick, red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


